# Objective-C: Where to initialize a delegate

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

I don´t fully understand how to use the Delegation pattern in obj-C. Basically I have a class: `DigGameControlLayer.h` and in it´s header I define a `protocol` with one required method that all users of this class needs to implement. Then I create the `delegate` property that I use within the code like any other property to delegate responsibility of what the `moveObjectToPosition:` method should do. So far so good I hope.

```
//DigGameControlLayer.h
@protocol DigGameControlLayerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) moveObjectToNewPosition: (CCSprite *)object atSpeed:(float)moveSpeed;
@end

@property (assign) id <DigGameControlLayerDelegate> delegate;
```

Then the class that is using that class (in this case DigCharacter) says it adheres to the `DigGameControlDelegate` protocol

```
@interface DigGoblinPlayer : DigCharacter <DigGameControlLayerDelegate>
```

But what I don´t understand is where do i Initialize and set the `delegate` property a declared? Cause currently it does nothing when I use it in `DigGameControlLayer` since it´s null

```
[self.delegate moveObjectToNewPosition:object atSpeed:moveSpeed];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the delegate in the init method like so:

```
DigGoblinPlayer* player;
player = [[DigGoblinPlayer alloc] initWithName:(NSString*)name delegate:self];
```

Or set it separately:

```
DigGoblinPlayer* player;
player = [[DigGoblinPlayer alloc] initWithName:(NSString*)name];
player.delegate = self;
```

Which style you choose depends on if you always want/need a delegate, or if you want to be able to change/reset it later on.

In some cases you don't want the delegate to be a public property; then you'd use the first style.

You see a lot of example of this in the iOS SDK like [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/initWithRequest%3adelegate%3a).

Note that `self` --which is just an example, and could an other object of course-- needs to implement this delegate.  And `name` is something I made up.

Comment: Got it working now,  thanks! Finally I understand the Delegation pattern - I don´t know why it was so hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

in DigGoblinPlayer

implement the method

```
-(void) moveObjectToNewPosition: (CCSprite *)object atSpeed:(float)moveSpeed
{
}
```

this method will be called when the method calls in DigGameControlLayer

```
[self.delegate moveObjectToNewPosition:object atSpeed:moveSpeed];
```